# Setting textView through a service

Tags: android, service, textview

I have an Intent service in different class which checks the database for new notifications. I'm accesing a TextView in that service which is in the MainActivity but it keeps giving me error. I know I have to put that textView.setText() line in a runOnUiThread() but i dont know how to do that in a service for a different activity. Can anyone show that to me? This is my code for the service

```
public class notificationIntentService extends IntentService {

public String c;
List<ParseObject> ob1;

public notificationIntentService(){
    super("notificationIntentService");

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    MainActivity.skip=0;

    // new notifyy().execute();
    MainActivity.counter=0;



    ParseUser l = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    String u = l.get("Name").toString();


    String a ="1";



    ParseQuery<ParseObject> q = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("RatingsAndNames");
    q.whereEqualTo("value",a);
    q.whereEqualTo("CreatedFor",u);
    try {
        ob1=q.find();
        for(ParseObject c1:ob1)
        {

            MainActivity.counter++;
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


     c = String.valueOf(MainActivity.counter);

//        MainActivity.notify.setText(c);
// I want to put the above  line in the UiThread


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bindService` to bind to the `IntentService` form the Activity. [This project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherAPI) is a spot on of what you want to achieve. Only difference is here they use a `Service` instead of `IntentService` (Big Thanks to @commonsware).